# SQL Server statistics for all tables within database

Tags: sql-server, optimizer-statistics

I want to use this query but every time I executed it the result was empty. Do you have any idea why?

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name FROM sys.tables

OPEN db_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        s.name AS statistics_name,
        c.name AS column_name,
        sc.stats_column_id
    FROM 
        sys.stats AS s 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.stats_columns AS sc ON s.object_id = sc.object_id 
                                AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns AS c ON sc.object_id = c.object_id 
                         AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
    WHERE 
        s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('@name');

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
END
```

Thank you very much,

David.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `@name` so that it isn't treated like a literal.

Comment: Also, no need for a cursor here.

Comment: Remove the cursor completely, and the where clause as @DanGuzman correctly commented on.

Comment: Thanks! the where clause wasn't necessary.